# EntitySet<IEnumerable<T>> to IEnumerable<T>

Tags: linq

I have an

```
 EntitySet<IEnumerable<T>>
```

returning from some query and need to cast it to

```
IEnumerable<T>.
```

Can I do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`EntitySet<IEnumerable<T>>` implements `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>`. So you can do this:

```
IEnumerable<T> flattenedList = entitySet.SelectMany(e => e);
```

Looks a little strange, but `SelectMany` takes a function that gets a "child list" from each item on a list and then concatenates all the child lists together into a single list. In this case, each item on the list is a list, so the lambda is nice and short.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a job for SelectMany